# Circle Geometry Colinear Points Problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

I was digging through some old questions I had from high school and I came across this circle geometry problem.

[image: Here is a picture of the problem].

There were no solutions unfortunately.

How can this be proven?

Here are a few things I've tried:

> Pascal's theorem
>
> Proof that $\angle EBF = \angle EAF$
>
> ABDC is a cyclic quadrilateral

I have been unsuccessful with all of these attempts, however I may have missed something when attempting to prove these.

Comment: Which country is this a high school problem from?

Comment: Here are some solutions using polars. https://gogeometry.blogspot.com/2016/02/geometry-problem-1189-circle-tangent.html

Comment: The purpose of this problem is to show the properties of polars and not vice versa. @rae306

Comment: @Aqua I thought so too, but it was the only thing I could find .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing notation a bit ...

Given $\bigcirc O$ and a point $P$ with tangent segments $\overline{PA}$ and $\overline{PB}$, introduce $\bigcirc P$ through $A$ and $B$. For $C$ and $D$ on $\bigcirc P$, let the extensions of $\overline{PC}$ and $\overline{PD}$ meet $\bigcirc O$ at points $C'$, $C''$, $D'$, $D''$, as shown:

[image]

Calculating the [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) of $P$ with respect to $\bigcirc O$ in three ways, we have
$$
pow_{\bigcirc O}P = |C'P||C''P| = |D'P||D''P|=|AP|^2 \quad\to\quad \begin{cases}|C'P||C''P|=|CP|^2\\[4pt] |D'P||D''P|=|DP|^2 \end{cases}
$$
Introduce $\bigcirc PC'D''$, and note
$$\begin{align}
pow_{\bigcirc P} C'' &= |C''P|^2-|CP|^2 \\[4pt]
&=|C''P|^2-|C'P||C''P| \\[4pt]
&=|C''P|(|C''P|-|C'P|) \\[4pt]
&=|C''P||C''C'| \\[4pt]
&=pow_{\bigcirc PC'D'}C''
\end{align}$$
Similarly, we have $pow_{\bigcirc P}D'=pow_{\bigcirc PC'D''}D'$. Since the points $C''$ and $D'$ each have the same powers with respect to $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc PC'D''$, they determine the *radical axis* of these circles. On the other hand, points $C'$ and $D''$, as the endpoints of the common chord of $\bigcirc O$ and $\bigcirc PC'D''$, determine the radical axis of *those* circles.

Thus, the point $X$, where these axes meet, has the same power with respect to $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc  PC'D''$, and the same power with respect to $\bigcirc PC'D''$ and $\bigcirc O$. Transitively, it has the same power with respect to $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc O$, and so it must lie on the radical axis of these circles, which is the line of the common chord $\overline{AB}$. $\square$

Comment: Nice...........

Answer (score 2):

The required claim follows from Problem 30.38.b from the last section of the first volume (“[Plane Geometry](http://e.math.hr/afine/planegeo.pdf)”) of the book “Problems in plane and solid geometry” by Viktor Prasolov.

> 30.38. a) Through point $P$ all secants of circle $S$ are drawn. Find the locus of the
>   intersection points of the tangents to $S$ drawn through the two intersection points of $S$ with
>   every secant.
>
> b) Through point $P$ the secants $AB$ and $CD$ of circle $S$ are drawn, where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are the intersection points of the secants with the circle. Find the locus of the intersection points of $AC$ and $BD$.

The proposed solution:

> 30.38. Let us consider, separately, the following two cases.
>
> 1) Point $P$ lies outside $S$. Let us make the projective transformation that sends circle $S$
>   into circle $S_1$ and point $P$ into $\infty$ (see Problem 30.17), i.e., the images of all lines passing through $P$ are parallel to each other. Then in heading b) the image of the locus to be found is line $\ell$, their common perpendicular passing through the center of $S_1$, and in heading a) the line $\ell$ with the diameter of $S_1$ deleted.
>
> To prove this, we have to make use of the symmetry through line $\ell$. Therefore, the locus
>   itself is: in heading b), the line passing through the tangent points of $S$ with the lines drawn
>   through point $P$ and in heading a), the part of this line lying outside $S$.
>
> 2) Point $P$ lies inside $S$. Let us make a projective transformation that sends circle $S$ into
>   circle $S_1$ and point $P$ into its center, cf. Problem 30.16 a). Then the image of the locus to
>   be found in both headings is the infinite line. Therefore, the locus itself is a line.
>
> The obtained line coincides for both headings with the polar line of point $P$ relative to
>   $S$, cf. Problem 30.19.

Answer (score 2):

Let $O$ be a circumcenter of the circle, let $M$ be a midpoint of segment (chord) $AB$ and let circles (blue) around $CHF$ and $DGF$ meet at $N$. Also let line $EF$ meet circle at $X$ and $Y$.

Let us prove that

- $ONEM$ is cyclic (yellow) and that
- $N$ is the midpoint of a chord $XY$.

This will mean that $\angle OME = 90^{\circ}$ and thus $E$ lies on $AB$.

**Lemma $0$.** Points $E,F$ and $N$ are collinear.

*Proof:* Point $E$ is on a radical axsis for circles $(FGD)$ and $(CHF)$: $$Pow(E,(FGD)) = EG\cdot ED = EC\cdot EH = Pow(E,(CHF))$$
 which is $NF$.

[image]

**Lemma $1$.** Points $D,H,N,E$ are concyclic (red circle).

*Proof:*  $$\angle EHN \equiv \angle CHN = \angle CFN = \angle GDN\equiv \angle EDN$$

**Lemma $2$.** We have $FX\cdot FY = FE\cdot FN$

*Proof:* $$FX\cdot FY = FH\cdot FD = FE\cdot FN$$

**Lemma $3$**. We have $EN\cdot EF = EX\cdot EY$

*Proof:* $$EN \cdot EF = EC\cdot EH = EX\cdot EY$$

---

Now let us prove that $N$ halves $XY$. Let $FX = s$, $EX= x$, $NE = z$ and $NY = y$.

From lemma 2 we have $$z(x+s)= x(y+z)$$
From lemma 3 we have $$ s(s+x+y+z) = (s+x)(s+x+z)$$

Combining these two (eliminate $s$) we get $y=x+z$ which means that $N$ halves $XY$ and we are done.

**Lemma $4$.** $ONEM$ is cyclic (yellow).

*Proof:* $OB\bot BF$ we see that $BF$ is tangent to circle (OMB), so $$FM\cdot FO = FB^2 = FH\cdot FD = FE\cdot FN$$